# How to benchmark databases (NoSQL & SQL) with Java

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, cassandra, benchmarking

I want to benchmark some databases, but I can't find a good Java library. I want to benchmark MySQL, MongoDB & Cassandra. I need the performance and the speed after inserting & reading data.
I saw some programs like JMeter, but I would like to use a library. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

To benchmark dissimilar products like those, you need to prototype *your* application in each product, then time it with realistic data.  This will require learning all three products well enough to write passable code for each.

In other words, you will not find a useful benchmark tool -- at any price -- that can give you the answer you desire.

After you have the results from that exercise, you should "play fair" by trying to further optimize the losing product.  Stackoverflow is littered with examples of speedups of a factor of 10 just by creating an 'index'.

Comment: Ok so i have to learn all and dont use librarys for that benchmark. 
I have to program 3 modules and measure the time in java for each program maybe?
Do you know if i  can measure the time before the code and after the code? 
Sorry im not sure, first time that i have to benchmark something :)

Comment: @JavaCoder - A benchmark tool automates running code, looking at the 'clock' before and after the code, then presenting how long the code took to run.  The tool can even fabricate _limited_ types of "typical" queries.  Benchmarks are great at saying "this disk drive is faster that that one", but not so good at the application-level comparison you are proposing.

Comment: @JavaCoder - Also,... The main performance difference will come from how many disk hits a program needs to do.  Since the 3 products you mention handle disk quite differently, this gets tricky.  Hence, my insistence that you actually code each one and optimizer it.  Otherwise the results will be unfair.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help :) I will write a program for all 3. databases and measure the clock time before and after. After that i will try to optimize it. I know a bit SQL but MongoDB and Cassandra are new to me. 
But i have enough time for it. So it will be ok :) 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JavaCoder - Great!  Also, by doing this exercise, you may decide that one db is easier to code for.  Programming effort is important, too.

Comment: yes, thanks for the help! Really nice :) 
Its the first time i post here. Normally i read only other questions.

Answer (score 3):

You might find that a tool like [NoSQLBench](https://www.datastax.com/blog/nosqlbench) might suit your needs. It's an open-source benchmarking suite that's pluggable so you can adapt it to your use case.

A huge +1 to Rick James' response -- so true that it's not an apples-for-apples comparison. I wanted to add that selecting a database is not just about performance although *arguably*, you'd find that some would stand out at true internet-scale and it narrows down the choice (full disclosure: I'm a Cassandra enthusiast at DataStax ).

Make sure that you don't only use benchmark results as your primary selection criteria. Any vendor can put out whatever benchmarks they want so consider them with a grain of salt (i.e. marketing fluff).

You need to take into account other factors such as support, community, scalability. Cheers!

Comment: Yes i know. Other factors are important, but i need this comparison for my bachelor thesis :)